# How to insert two different drop down select into database as an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Drop down html code,

```
<div class="form-group">
     <%= f.label :Assign_Role_1, :class => 'control-label col-lg-2' %>
     <div class="col-lg-10" >
     <%= f.select(:role_id, Role.all.map{|e| [e.name, e.id]},{ :include_blank => "Please select" }, { class: 'form-control' } ) %>
</div>
 <%=f.error_span(:Assign_Role) %>
 </div>



<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :Assign_Role_2, :class => 'control-label col-lg-2' %>
  <div class="col-lg-10" >
  <%= f.select(:role_id, Role.all.map{|e| [e.name, e.id]},{ :include_blank => "Please select" }, { class: 'form-control' } ) %>
  </div>
  <%= f.error_span(:Assign_Role) %>
  </div>
```

I need to select the role name from both the drop down and insert the value to `roll_id` attribute as an array. I have used `has_many_through` association.

In controller,

```
def userrole_params
  params.require(:user_role).permit( :role_id, :user_id)
end
```

How do I insert it as an array?

Comment: Please add code of your create action in user role controller

Comment: Please check my updated answer, you can also do something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of 2 drop down, add option to select multiple roles from single select box

```
<%= f.select(:role_ids, Role.all.map{|e| [e.name, e.id]},{ include_blank: "Please select", multiple: true}, { class: 'form-control' } ) %>
#
# Single drop down
```

Please after doing this check your logs, what you are getting parameters you must get array in role_id parameter

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_role][:user_id])
  @user.roles << Role.find(params[:user_role][:role_ids])
  #params[:user_role][:role_id].each do |role_id|
   # @user.roles.create(role_id: role_id)
  #end
end
```

Comment: @Sneha check my updated answer, but it is very wrong method to save data

Comment: Thank you. that worked with few changes made @Vishal